# Get some integers from DynamoDB column on a table and calculate their sum

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb

In my DynamoDB table I have 2 columns: One with Strings, called 'id', and the other one with integers, called 'price'.

In my app, I have IDs, saved in a `String[]`. I want to get the price for each of the IDs and to calculate their sum.

I already have the DynamoDB Mapper class:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Products")
public class Product {

    private String id;
    private String price;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "price")
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

What I need is to know how can I get only the prices of the IDs in the array, and to calculate their sum. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB can't do the summing for you, so you need to handle that at application layer.

Pseudo-code (which might not compile as is):

```
List<Product> itemsToGet;
for (int i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
    Product p = new Product();
    p.setId(idArray[i]);

    itemsToGet.add(p);
}
Map<String, List<Object>> items = dynamoDBMapper.batchLoad(itemsToGet);
Map.Entry<String, List<Object>> firstEntry = items.entrySet().iterator().next();  // the Map will contain only one entry, because you are querying for only one table.
List<Product> productsFromDynamoDB = firstEntry.getValue();
```

From `productsFromDynamoDB`, you can fetch `price` for all `Product`s and sum them up.